# Networkx: When adding attributes by looping through the list of nodes, IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, nodes, networkx, opencsv, index-error

Problem with Networkx in Python:

I uploaded my csv file into Python using delimiter ','. I have now a nodelist and an edgelist. When I am trying to assign attributes from the csv (node) file to an empty dictionary, I receive the error;

IndexError: list index out of range

Herbey I added a piece of my code.

```
nodereader = csv.reader(nodecsv, delimiter=(','))
nodes= [n for n in nodereader][1:]

node_names = [n[0] for n in nodes] # List 1


household_dict = {}
household_dict[node[0]]=node[2]
```

Why is it not working?? The problem is that my code does not separate every row into different columns. Below the structure of the csv file.

CSV file (only one column):

Id,Label,Household,Producer,Surplus

0,Klant1,2,Ja,1
1,Klant2,2,Nee,0
2,Klant3,4,Nee,0

Comment: Whenever you get an error where you think a variable is defined and it isn't, it's worth putting a print statement the line before.  Try `for n in nodes: print(n)` I'm betting that that empty line between the headers and the node names is your problem.  You'll probably see an empty row get printed.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately, print(n) shows the first row : 0,Klant1,2Ja,2. And: for n in nodes: print(n) , shows the entire excel correct

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to dive into the nodes that you are extracting from the file. However, see below the general syntax for parsing csv. You can adjust it to your purpose easily.

```
with open('filePath\\fileName.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        print(f'\tID: {row["Id"]}, Label: {row["Label"]}, Household: {row["Household"]}, Producer: {row["Producer"]}, Surplus: {row["Surplus"]}')
        line_count += 1
    print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
```

Comment: Second part is still returning an error                            
---------------------------------------------------                                                                                       
 Column names are Id,Label,Household,Producer,Surplus

-----------------------------------------------------
----> 8         print(f'\tID: {row["Id"]}, Label: {row["Label"]}, Household: {row["Household"]}, Producer: {row["Producer"]}, Surplus: {row["Surplus"]}')
      9         line_count += 1
     10     print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')

-------KeyError: 'Id'